# What is the probability a student chose football given that they like watching sports?

Tags: probability, statistics

This equation comes from Edgenuity's course of Statistics, and I am taking the course as a high school senior. I understand that to find $P(A$|$B)$, one divides $P(A$ and $B)$ by $P(B)$. I attempt to do this in my solving of the problem below:

**Some randomly selected high school students were asked to name their favorite sport to watch. The table displays the distribution of results.**

[image]

**What is the probability that a student chose football given that they like watching sports?**

First, to find $P($Like watching sports and choosing football$)$, I multiplied $0.23$ and $0.84$ (found by adding all of the probabilities of those who chose a certain sport in the chart), which equals $0.1932$. I divided $0.1932$ by $P($Like watching sports$)$, which is $0.84$. $P($Choosing football | Like watching sports$)$ is then $0.23$. Are my methods and answer correct? If not, please explain why.

Comment: $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)P(B)$ is not generally true. It is true when $A$ and $B$ are independent. But “watches sports” and “prefers watching football” are not independent. Indeed, $A=$“prefers watching football” implies $B=$“watches sports.” So $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product rule is that: the probability for the intersection of *independent* events equals the product of the probabilities for each event.

However, liking football and liking sport are **not** independent events; since if you do not like sport you certainly will not like football.   So this rule is **inapplicable**.

Indeed, liking football is *a subset* of liking sport.   So the event of doing both is simply the event of liking football. That has a probability of $0.23$.

So by definition of conditional probability; $$\mathsf P(\text{Like(Football)}\mid\text{Like(A Sport)})=\dfrac{23}{84}$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems like to get your answer, you should be able to just take .23/.84, part of a whole.

What you just did was multiply .23 by .84, then divide it by .84, so you don’t get what you were looking for unless there’s something I’m missing.